# Efficient Way of Filtering URLs by looking through keyword list

Tags: c, url, filtering, blacklist

What is the best way to filter urls by comparing where a keyword is inside the url or not?
I have a list of keywords (a kind of blacklist) which contains 50000 words. 
The search method uses the following steps:

While (end of keywords)
 1. Get the keyword from database
 2. Check whether the keyword is in the url
 3. Redirect the user to a specific page.

When I use this method, the cpu usage becomes  around %90. Is there an efficient way to do this? It seems that I can't use regex, since the keyword always changes.

Comment: Build a balanced binary tree of the keywords and search that. 5000 keywords isn't too much for an in-memory data structure.

Comment: Thanks Paul. It is 50 000 and it will increase in time. This will be a like a backward search. Lets say my url is www.selldrugs.com. I have a list of keywords which has drug in it. I have to get the keywords one by one and then call doesUrlContainsKeyword() method. If the keyword is 50 000th keyword, then it is a problem.

Comment: 50.000 keywords still shouldn't be a problem for an in-memory data structure on a 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is multi pattern search and can be effectively solved with Aho-Coracisk algorithm. This algorithm searches a set of strings simultaneously. The complexity of the algorithm is linear in the length of the keyowords plus the length of the URL plus the number of output matches.

Comment: Thank you Marcin. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. Check whether the keyword is in the url
>      [...]
>      Is there an efficient way to do this?

The vice versa will be much more efficient: split the URL onto the keywords and lookup them in the database.

To speed up the database lookup, you can use a variety of methods. For example, sort the database and do a binary search, use a trie structure, hash table, etc etc.

Comment: Thanks Andriy. If I a url contains 2000 characters, I have to create keyword combinations with 2000 characters. Wouldn't that cost much?

Comment: Sure, you need keyword separators to split URL efficiently. IMO it makes sense for the filtration, since sex and unisex might have quite different meaning. But sure, it is up to you and it is just my 2 cents...

Answer (score 0):

Aho-Corasick algorithm is the best solution for this problem.
Here is the python implementation [Aho-Corasick](https://github.com/WojciechMula/pyahocorasick/)

Below is a code sample

```
import ahocorasick  
A = ahocorasick.Automaton()  
for index, word in enumerate('asim sinan yuksel uksel sel sina sim asi as nan an in ina uks .com .co www. http//'.split()):  
   A.add_word(word, (index, word))
A.make_automaton()  
for item in A.iter('http://wwww.asimsinanyuksel.com'):  
   print(item)
```